# Objective C how to remove items from array based on other arrays items

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have three UIPickerviews. I have a json response. I have a three text fields. If user select first picker view the related data is displaying in first textfields. And second and third picker view also same. My requirement Is if user select the the particular item in first picker view second and third picker view does not showing the item. And second and third also same.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A+",@"A-",@"B+",@"B-",@"O+",@"O-", nil];

    bloodGroup = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, logoImg.frame.origin.y+logoImg.frame.size.height+45, screenWidth-20, 50)];

    bloodGroup.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    bloodGroup.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    bloodGroup.placeholder = @"Please Select Your Option";
    bloodGroup.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:bloodGroup];

    txtField1 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, ansField1.frame.origin.y+ansField1.frame.size.height+45, screenWidth-20, 50)];
    txtField1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    txtField1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    txtField1.placeholder = @"Please Select Your Option";
    txtField1.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:txtField1];

    txtField2 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, ansField2.frame.origin.y+ansField2.frame.size.height+45, screenWidth-20, 50)];
    txtField2.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    txtField2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    txtField2.placeholder = @"Please Select Your Option";
    txtField2.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:txtField2];

    myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    [myPickerView setDataSource: self];
    [myPickerView setDelegate: self];
    myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

    bloodGroup.inputView = myPickerView;
    bloodGroup.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

    // txtField1

    txtField1.inputView = myPickerView;
    txtField1.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

    txtField2.inputView = myPickerView;
    txtField2.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {

    if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(!isBloodGroupFieldSelected){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {
        return [dataArray count];
    }
    else if(!isBloodGroupFieldSelected)
    {
        return [dataArray count];
    }
    else if (!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)
    {
        return [dataArray count];
    }
    return 0;
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

  if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected)
    {
        return dataArray[row];
    }
    else if((!isBloodGroupFieldSelected) && (isGenderGroupFieldSelected))
    {
        return dataArray[row];
    }
    else if(!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)
    {
        return dataArray[row];
    }
    return 0;
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {
        bloodGroup.text = dataArray[row];
    }
    else if((!isBloodGroupFieldSelected) && (isGenderGroupFieldSelected))
    {
        txtField1.text = dataArray[row];
    }
    else if(!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)
    {
        txtField2.text= dataArray[row];
    }
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField == bloodGroup) {
        isBloodGroupFieldSelected = YES;
    }
    else if (textField == txtField1){
        isBloodGroupFieldSelected = NO;
        isGenderGroupFieldSelected = YES;
    }
    else if (textField == txtField2) {
        isGenderGroupFieldSelected = NO;
        isBloodGroupFieldSelected = NO;
    }
    [myPickerView reloadAllComponents];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have most of the code you need already. The `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` delegate method will be called when any of your pickers have been changed, assuming they each have their delegates set to the controller above. Although, I only see one picker view defined in the code above. Let's assume your picker views are called `myPickerView`, `myPickerView2`, and `myPickerView3`. The code would roughly be:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
      didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView == pickerView1) {
        // the first picker view lseection has changed
        // update myPickerView2 and myPickerView3 to reflect
        // the values you want based on this selection
    } else if (pickerView == pickerView2) {
        // update the other views based on this selection
    } else ...

    ....

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i am using single picker view. please explain full code.